# Array not populating from For Loop VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to create an array of cell entries (e.g. A6,B6, etc) that populates in a for loop.

However the array

```
    MyArray
```

is always empty and I can't figure out why its not being populated within the for loop. Below is (the appropriate part of-the code is doing other stuff to) my code:

```
    Sub ListSheets()

    ' Defining all variables (objects) used within the code, establishing their
    'classes                                   

   Dim i As Integer
   Dim array_size As Integer
   Dim MyArray() As String

   array_size = 26
   ReDim MyArray(array_size) As String

   For intLoop = 1 To 26
   MyArray(intLoop, 1) = Chr$(64 + intLoop) + "6"
   Next

   Set CopyFrom = MyArray
   Sheets("vba_deposit").Range("A1").Resize(CopyFrom.Rows.Count).Value = CopyFrom.Value

   End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `MyArray(intLoop, 1) = ...` -> `MyArray(intLoop) = ...`

Comment: Hi simoco, I've removed the "1" as advised but I've still getting an empty MyArray and thus "Object Required" compile error. To confirm is that the only line that needs correcting? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I changed my opinion, it's better to use `MyArray(intLoop, 1)` but with `ReDim MyArray(1 To array_size, 1 To 1)`. See my answer below

Comment: @simoco - No need to use `MyArray(intLoop, 1)` or making it a 2-D array. You simply need to start your loop from 0 rather than 1.

Comment: @PankajJaju, in that case you'd get horizontal array and can't do `Range(...).Value = MyArray` for vertical range. See my answer

Comment: Works for me though ... all I needed to change the original code was to make sure loop starts from 0, change the 2-D notation inside the loop for MyArray and change the last line to `Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(MyArray)).Value = MyArray`. I dont know why copying of Array was needed; so removed it.

Comment: Ahh ... now i see ... what was the expected output. My bad. :P

Comment: @PankajJaju, it writes in each cell of `A1:A26` always _first_ element of `MyArray` (in 1D case), but not each element

Comment: @vbastrangledpython - going off the line here ... but cool name :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub ListSheets()
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim array_size As Integer
   Dim MyArray() As String

   array_size = 26
   ReDim MyArray(1 To array_size, 1 To 1)

   For intLoop = 1 To 26
        MyArray(intLoop, 1) = Chr$(64 + intLoop) + "6"
   Next

   Sheets("vba_deposit").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(MyArray)).Value = MyArray    
End Sub
```

Your first idea to use `MyArray(intLoop, 1)` was good - because in that case there is no need to use `Transpose` (which not always working since it has limitation on number of elements in array) here: `Range(...).Value = MyArray`. However I've made little changes in your code:

- redim array as 2D: `ReDim MyArray(1 To array_size, 1 To 1)`
- use direct `Range(...).Value = MyArray`

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ListSheets()

' Defining all variables (objects) used within the code, establishing their
'classes

 Dim i As Integer
 Dim array_size As Integer
 Dim MyArray() As String

 array_size = 26
 ReDim MyArray(array_size) As String

 For intloop = 1 To 26
 MyArray(intloop) = Chr$(64 + intloop) + "6"
 Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(intloop - 1).Value = MyArray(intloop)
 Next
 'An array is not an object, you can't use SET with them.
 'Your array is 1-dimensional, MyArray(1,1) won't work as that's 2-dimensional, just
 'MyArray(1) = "whatever1"       MyArray(2) = "whatever2" etc. etc.
 End Sub
```